# SwiftUI: Gradient fill not showing up

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, linear-gradients

The following code produces a `Rectangle()` that is white and un-filled. I have zero ideas why, and I'm not getting any errors.

**Note:** When I replace the custom colors (i.e. `Color(red: green: blue:)` with built-in colors such as `Color.red` or `Color.blue`, fill shows up and is colored.

```
var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(
                LinearGradient(
                    colors: [Color(red: 180, green: 40, blue: 55),
                             Color(red: 200, green: 40, blue: 55)],
                    startPoint: .top,
                    endPoint: .bottom)
            )
    }
```

What's making the fill not show up, and how can I fix this while keeping my custom colors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Color` initializer you're using defines the color using the sRGB color space and clamps any supplied component values to between 0 and 1. So supplying any value greater than 1 for all three values will create a white color - the equivalent of `Color(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0)`.

To get the colors you need, you should divide each value by 255, e.g.:

```swift
colors: [Color(red: 0.706, green: 0.157, blue: 0.216),
         Color(red: 0.784, green: 0.157, blue: 0.216)],
```

See the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color).

Comment: I'm clueless... I forgot to put the values as fractions over 255... thank you!